# Who's In Charge Of DADA 19 Years Later?

Tags: harry-potter, defence-against-the-dark-arts

Seeing that Defense Against the Dark Arts is a crucial subject, both in Harry's life as well as a part of the school-going wizard's curriculum, it must be in the hands of a good professor.

Is it known who Minerva McGonagall appointed as DADA prof. once she was made Headmistress. Was it someone we know or was it just a random powerful wizard. Is there any information about this available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The books and most other canon sources have bupkiss on this point. All we know for certain is that McGonagall is headmistress as of the end of the "present-day" (pre-epilogue) plotline, and that it's most likely not Neville (who eventually becomes the Herbology prof) nor Kingsley (who becomes Minister of Magic) nor HH&R (who are all left on the platform at the end of the epilogue; if they were professors of any subject they'd be on that train, or already at Hogwarts).

Most likely, the position is held by a former Auror, someone close to or in the Order and thus has ties to the school and to McGonagall; there are a few of them introduced through canon who (I think) are still alive at the end of the battle. Emmeline Vance comes to mind as one of those random Aurors (she was part of the advance guard that took Harry to Grimmauld Place in book 5), but I can't say for certain if she made it (EDIT: As per N. Unnikrishnan's comment, Emmeline Vance was killed prior to the events of HBP, so definitely not her).

Comment: It occurs to me...Hermione was on the platform...but I can't think of any better profession for her other than teacher at Hogwarts...now I'm wondering what she's doing for a living if not being a professor...Maybe still working on a magical dissertation?

Comment: @Zibbobz She works at the ministry as a 'Lawyer'

Comment: Emmeline Vance was killed by Voldemort "in the Prime Minister's backyard" before the beginning of _the Half Blood Prince_, as reported by Fudge to the PM.

Comment: I wouldn't say that because HH&R where on the platform and didn't take the train that it rules them out. They could very well want to drop off their children at the train station for the first year and still travel back on their own before the train reaches the school.

Comment: Well, there are other things, such as the fact that the parents asked their children to give Neville their love; that heavily implies the grown-ups won't be around at Hogwarts to do that. It would make a lot of sense for Harry to be invited as a guest lecturer to a few DADA classes, but from non-canon sources Harry and Ron made it into the Auror program (either having been given an honorary "graduation" from Hogwarts or just taking their 7th year over) while Hermione also works in Magical Law, and it's unclear what Ginny does but she's possibly been a housewife while the kids grew up).

Comment: Ginny is a reporter for the Daily Prophet as of Rowling's updates on Pottermore

Answer (score 11):

Searching the book and Accio Quote shows zip.

McGonagall probably didn't appoint him, since as per [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogwarts_staff):

> As is confirmed in The Tales of Beedle the Bard, McGonagall becomes Headmistress of Hogwarts after the Battle of Hogwarts and Snape's death; however, in an interview Rowling said McGonagall would be retired by the time of the Deathly Hallows epilogue (19 years after the main events of Deathly Hallows), as she is "getting on in years."

The closest we have (from that same set of [interviews](http://www.beyondhogwarts.com/harry-potter/articles/jk-rowling-goes-beyond-the-epilogue.html)) is:

> **Also, there is a new Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher, and that position is now as safe as the other teaching posts at Hogwarts**, since Voldemort's death broke the jinx that kept a Defense Against the Dark Arts professor from remaining for more than a year.
>
> J.K. didn't clarify whether Harry, Ron and Hermione ever return to school to finish their seventh year, but she did say she could see Harry making an appearance every now and again to give the "odd talk" on Defense Against the Dark Arts.

Comment: Presumably the one term curse had been lifted, it's possible that a McGonagall appointee would still hold the position.

Comment: @TGnat - You have a point

Comment: I seem to recall another interview where she confirmed that Hermione DID complete her seventh year...think there's even a question that addresses that...ah, right here. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21926/20533

Comment: What is the "Odd Talk" ?

Comment: Odd in this case means rare/unusual.

Comment: @DVK Unless it were Luna Lovegood coming to give the talk, in which case it really would be an odd talk. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is either **Neville Longbottom** or **Pomona Sprout**.  They can't both be Herbology professors, and likely both of them are qualified to teach either Herbology or Defense Against the Dark Arts.  They must have split in some way, possibly both of them teaching half of either class.

Of course, it's possible that Professor Sprout would have retired by that time, but I hope she hasn't.

The sad part is, had Remus Lupin survived, he would have made an awesome DADA teacher again, as parents would be more likely to accept him as a professor after the War, having seen that there are much worse things a Hogwarts professor can be than a werewolf.

The real question, though, is who would teach Potions?  It seems there are very few people qualified for that position, Professor Slughorn would be retired again, and Professor Snape has died.

Comment: Neville is stated to be the Herbology professor. While he may also be head of Gryffindor House, the Headmaster typically does not teach a class themselves, and so since we know Neville does, he's unlikely to have the post.

Comment: Pomona Sprout could be the DADA teacher if she hasn't retired yet. That's an interesting idea. Maybe there will be a canon answer in the play.