# Did the trio (and others) go back to finish at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry, Ron and Hermione skip school in the final book to hunt down the Horcruxes.

And [1999](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/1999) is the year Hermione supposedly graduates from Hogwarts, but the article has no citation and doesn't mention Ron or Harry returning.

Do they or anyone else from the Battle of Hogwarts return to finish that year? I'm looking for canon sources here, or even better Word of Author.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Harry and Ron did not return to Hogwarts after Voldemort's defeat. Hermione did and she completed her N.E.W.T.s.

> SU: Oh, (MA:Well, did...) speaking of Ron and Hermione-
>   JKR: Yeah, did they graduate from Hogwarts?
>   SU: Yes. Did they?
>   JKR: Harry and Ron didn't go back. Hermione did.
>   SU: (gasps) Ooo!
>   MA:Oh my-
>   JKR: Did you bet right? I mean, come on, nobody's going to think Hermione wouldn't go back.
>   SU: I predicted. Yeah.
>   JKR: Of course she'd go back. She has to get her N.E.W.T.s. Ron was really done with schooling (laughs). I think that (SU: Yeah.) it would be kind of tempting to go back just to mess around for a year and have a break, but he goes (JN: Yeah.) into the Auror Department. He's needed. Anyone who was in that battle the right side. Kingsley would want them to help clean up the- I mean anyone who's old enough to do it, who's over age (JN: Hm.), but Kinglsey would have wanted Ron, Neville, Harry, and they would've all gone, and they would've all done the job. And I think that would've been a good thing for them too, because to go through that battle, and them be relegated to the sidelines, I think they would've felt a need to keep going, and finish the job. So that would've have been rounding up the corrupt people who were doing a Lucius Malfoy, and trying to pretend that they really weren't involved.
>   <sub>[**[J.K. Rowling Interview with The Leaky Cauldron - 12.23.07]**](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/12/23/transcript-of-part-1-of-pottercast-s-jk-rowling-interview)</sub>

And there is the author's word :)

Comment: They deserved a *Honoris Causa*!

Comment: You would think beating Voldemort one-on-one would get you an honorary certificate or something. Then again, from what little the Epilogue tells you, it doesn't look like the three were doing much in the way of wizardry afterwards.

Comment: @Jersey: Which was very lame of the epilogue.  (I seem to recall that JKR has said in interviews that Harry went into the Auror Dept., and held guest lectures at Hogwarts for DAtDA classes.)

Comment: Did Harry or Ron get the Wizard equivalent of a GED?  Maybe with an "I fought Voldemorte" patch?

Comment: @Jeff - Nope, no GED or A Levels. I think that Harry is his own "I fought Voldemort and all I got was this lousy t-shirt" badge. Yes, Harry became an Auror; JKR said he does indeed return to Hogwarts for the occasional guest lecture. Depending on which JKR canon you prefer -- because she's on the record with both -- Ron either became an Auror or went to work at Weasleys' Wizarding Wheezes with George and was a very successful business man there. Only Hermione technically became a "fully qualified witch". I would hope Harry would at least warrant a bank holiday or something!

Comment: By all your comments, it seems you are all wizards and the wizard world is completely real. The battle, Harry and all, they are real, C'mon...

Comment: @AwalGarg - *‘Of course it is happening inside your head, Harry, but why on earth should that mean that it is not real?’* Nobody's hurting anyone. Why worry?

Comment: I'd like to say that Neville went back to Hogwarts to complete his studies, since he later went on to become Herbology Professor, but considering the quality of some of Harry's Defense Against the Dark Arts teachers I'm not sure there are any criteria that need to be met prior to being employed as a Hogwarts teacher.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Good point! Wanted: Defence Against the Dark Arts instructor for large magical educational institution. The successful candidate will possess a turban and the Dark Lord in the brain stem, a smile worthy of *Witch Weekly*, a socially maligned medical condition, more than one prosthetic, a trunk full of pink knickers and a collection of decorative kitten plates, an incredibly ridiculous grudge against a child and a lengthy unrequited love for said child's mother, and a fraternal twin with whom to co-teach. Applications to be sent to Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. :P

Comment: @Slytherincess I'd never once considered Umbridge's knickers before now, so *thank you so much* for correcting that. :P

Comment: @AnthonyGrist -- I'm so glad to have been of great help! (There weren't enough characters left to also address the issue of the centaurs ... ) :D

Comment: @Slytherincess You win, I haven't yet seen so strong an argument. Hail!

Comment: As to the suggestion that honorary diplomas should be awarded to Harry, Ron, and Neville, I would say "forget it". They are embarrassed enough with the history that has accumulated around them. Just let them go along quietly and unassumingly, doing the jobs that the Ministry of Magic has conferred upon them. Let them work in peace.