# Why weren't other schools included in the Triwizard Tournament?

Tags: harry-potter, triwizard-tournament

It's well-known at this point that [there are several magical schools other than Hogwarts, Beauxbaton, and Durmstrang](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13575/57281). It's also been noted that [the Triwizard Tournament probably did not continue after 1994](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21871/did-the-triwizard-tournament-continue-after-1994).

Out of curiosity, is there any in-universe reason given for why the other schools weren't included in the tournament (either in its original incarnation or the 1994 not-so-greatest-hits edition) to begin with? This is putting aside the "triwizard" assumption, of course.

Comment: @Edlothiad: No worries :) I'm curious if there were any in-universe (or even really out-of-universe) reasons given for why it became the "triwizard" tourney in the first place. Were these the only 3 schools interested/insane enough? Was it magical elitism? Did something eat the owls delivering invites to the other schools? You get the idea.

Comment: I think it originated before the other schools were founded, some 700 years ago (in-universe) and Rowling only thought about having other schools later I guess, not sure if that's true or not but that would be out-of-universe.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The Triwizard tournament was held between the **[three biggest](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Triwizard_Tournament)** wizarding schools in Europe (emphasis mine).

> "The Triwizard Tournament was first established some seven hundred years ago, as a friendly competition between the **three largest European** schools of wizardry - Hogwarts, Beauxbatons and Durmstrang.
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 12, The Triwizard Tournament)*.</sub>

The three biggest schools in Europe were Hogwarts, Beauxbatons and Drumstrang. As such, they were the three schools that contested the tournament.

Comment: A real life example would be [the boat race on the Thames between Oxford and Cambridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boat_Race). Yes, there are other universities, but these are the ones that have been competing since _time immemorial_ (well, okay, 1829).

Comment: It looks like the 6 Nations tournament in rugby: there are many European nations in the International Rugby Board, but this event is organized only between 6 of them (France, UK, Ireland, Wales, Scotland, and Italy).

Comment: It always makes me laugh when the Triwizard Tournament, the contest discontinued due to its unacceptably high death toll, is referred to in the HP universe as a "friendly competition".

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Witches and wizards are hardcore.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - nothing unfriendly about wizards getting killed, as long as it's done fairly. :-)

Comment: @DisturbedNeo: "Friendly" should perhaps be interpreted in the same sense as found in "friendly fire". :-)

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Friendly competition can be dangerous without the contestants being a danger to each other. I mean, dragons? An hour underwater swim with who knows what creatures? Also, it can be friendly between schools even though the contestants are bitter rivals.

Comment: @SQB: In fairness, no one alive today (well, I assume) remembers 1829. So it truly is "time immemorial".

Comment: @SQB Actually, [Time Immemorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_immemorial) was defined in 1275 as starting on 6th July 1189 (the date Richard I ascended the throne).