# Does Harry Potter go back to school after the Deathly Hallows

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

At the start of the franchise, we see Harry join Hogwarts, starting his schooling journey as a young wizard, but due to the fact he has to fight against the Dark Lord, his school career ends up taking a back burner, unsurprisingly.

But it is never confirmed whether or not Harry returns to the school with the rest of his peers after he has defeated Lord Voldemort to finish learning from the teachers in order to become the best possible wizard he can be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did the trio (and others) go back to finish at Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21870/did-the-trio-and-others-go-back-to-finish-at-hogwarts)

Comment: Yes it does, thankyou JQL